# Add column to liferay

Tags: liferay, theming

How can I add 'areas' to a liferay site that applications can be displayed in? I currently have a 3 column layout (created though the UI) and I need to add a footer below.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom layouts in Liferay.

See http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template

Answer (score 0):

A footer in Liferay is something that you'd usually place in a [Liferay theme](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Themes+v6.0) unless you actually want to be able to place portlets in the footer and change them regularly. If you plan to change them often, a [custom layout template](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Layout+Template) can be an option, but if you just want a couple of fixed portlets in the footer you can [embed them in a theme](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Embedding+a+portlet+in+the+theme).

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your question it seems like you want to embed portlets(applications) in footer.
To make it working you will have to create a theme and in that modify code of portal_normal.vm file.

Add your portlet(application) in footer section and it will be available across your site.

```
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('display-style', '1'))
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.setValue('portlet-setup-show-borders', 'false'))
#set ($instanceId = 'E3j7')
#set ($myPortletId = "73_INSTANCE_${instanceId}")$theme.runtime($myPortletId, '', $velocityPortletPreferences.toString())
#set ($VOID = $velocityPortletPreferences.reset())
```

You can specify values to your app that will automatically reflect when your theme will be hot deployed.